# Can FindBugs be used to flag code that uses a method that's been blacklisted?

Tags: java, findbugs

We're trying to move our very large codebase from Guava 11 to Guava 14 and would like to catch uses of removed or deprecated APIs. Can FindBugs perform such checking? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to just use Oracle's Java compiler `javac` to do this.

Removed methods in the API would result in compiler errors if they are used so it should be possible to find these by compiling the code.

Deprecated methods can be found using the javac `-deprecation` option. More on `-deprecation` here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: Our codebase is a vast forest of modules with (currently) unknown dependencies and different ways of building themselves. If Guava 14 were thrown out there, lots of builds will break (perhaps having runtime errors) and can't be fixed until their dependencies are fixed.

Comment: So what's the problem?  You now know which dependencies need fixing.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem either. You don't have to "through Guava 14 out there". Just do the compilation locally before committing anything.

Comment: If you consider the migration from Guava 11 to 14 a long running task, if you don't want to diverge too much while you remove bad usages, it makes sense to track them using something other than 'upgrade temporarily and try to compile'.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use PMD [Sourceforge](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) for this task. There are rules out there that let you find deprecated methods

Comment: I would love if you mention theses rules names

Answer (score 1):

One aspect that I believe `javac` will not cover is if you cannot change the 3rd party code to add `@Deprecated` annotations. If you just want to avoid a method which has not been marked as deprecated, you can use this plugin I wrote for FindBugs:

https://github.com/Grundlefleck/FindBugs4Deprecating3rdParty

There's very little documentation, so you may need to explore a little yourself. It allows configuring methods and classes to avoid in a properties file. I use it to deprecate `org.junit.Assert.assertThat`.